# What are the uses of beacons?

Tags: wifi

If probe response packets announces the capabilities of a network,
    then what is the purpose of Beacon frames in wireless 802.11 ?

Answer (score 0):

Among other things, beacons allow a device to passively scan all channels for available Access Points so that a list may be presented to a user showing signal strength. They also allow a device to detect if there is another Access Point on the same network and presumably on a different channel with a better signal.